# Running Ubuntu on HP 250

Tags: system-installation, hp

I am a ubuntu n00b! I have decided to install it on my HP 250. However, I am having video problems. I think it is the video driver. When Ubuntu boots up the screen is black. It will stay black unless I plug it into another screen. Then it works event if I unplug it. If the monitor goes to sleep It will not come back up. Since I was running W8 just fine I do not think IT is a physical problem with the hardware. Where can I find this driver or is ther a factory disk for my computer? Thanks!!!

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201301-12667/components/

Comment: Turns out the problem was that the brightness was turned all the way down everytime the computer was restarted. By googling I found a way to turn the brightness up everytime the computer starts.

Answer (score 1):

i have a HP 250 G2 too with Intel HD Graphics 4000. I don´t have any problem with graphics when i install Ubuntu 14.04. I recommend you to install this driver on your first start of ubuntu.

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Bye.